# Custom DateTime format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

What's the DateTime format `"2011-09-12T10:28:55Z"`?
How can I get it using ToString()?
I didn't get any information in Microsoft's documents about it. Nothing similar like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that using ToString with:

```
var text = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I don't believe there's a standard date/time format which covers this, unfortunately.

Of course, if it's not already a UTC date/time then it'll be lying (that's what the 'Z' bit means). You can call `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` to convert it, of course.