# Datetime Custom format - Show AM/PM as capitalized and not am / pm

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

I have a `string` which contains: **14 Dec 2011 9:45 am** (take note that "AM" is not capitalized")

now I wanted to create a `datetime` variable with it.

I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581487/custom-datetime-format), but it is the opposite of what I wanted.
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862937/convert-string-to-datetime-in-vb-net), but failed.
What I've tried so far is this:

```
Dim dateNow As DateTime
Dim out As String = "14 Dec 2011 9:45 am"
dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(out, "d MMM yyyy HH:mm tt", Nothing)
```

But sadly it's not working. Any idea? Thanks. VB.net Or C# code will be okay..

Comment: check for System.FormatException message

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTime.Parse()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your probably need single `H` instead of `HH` as the hour is single digit in the `datetime` string. You should have `09` has hour if you have `HH` for hour. Also use small h for 12 hours with AM and PM, Capital `H` is for **24 hours** time format, like `1:28 PM` would be `13:28 PM`

```
dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(out, "d MMM yyyy h:mm tt", Nothing)
```

The description abut using different options for hour shown below.

[image]

You can learn more about custom formats for `DataTime` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey Adil, thanks. I tried it but it is giving me "String was not recognized as a valid datetime." The string is: "21 Sep 2011 1:28 pm"
I don't understand why it is happening, everything seems so perfect

Comment: You need small h, for 12 hours AM, PM, check my updated answer.

Comment: Hey thanks. It worked now. But could you please tell me what happened by simply changing H to h?

Comment: Capital H is for 24 hours, like 1:28 PM would be 13:28 PM

Answer (score 2):

Try to give like this `14 Dec 2011 09:45` am add 0 near  hour 9.

```
Dim dateNow As DateTime
Dim out As String = "14 Dec 2011 09:45 am"
dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(out, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm tt", Nothing)
```

check out [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an **array** of allowed formats like this:

```
    Dim dateNow As DateTime
    Dim out As String = "14 Dec 2011 12:45 am"
    Dim allowedFormats() As String = {"d MMM yyyy h:mm tt", "dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt", "d MMM yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt"}
    dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(out, allowedFormats, Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```